# geolocator 6.0.0+1 distanceBetween() not working in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, geolocation

i hope everyone is safe i am using flutter,and i want to calculate distance between two locations so i have installed **geolocator 6.0.0+1** from pub.dev [here](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator), with that i can find the location of user but i cannot use the inbuilt method called ** distanceBetween()** which is used to calculate the distance between two latitudes and longitudes, it shows me a error whis says **The method 'distanceBetween' isn't defined for the type '_RegisterState'.
** i have used the method as shown in the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)

here is my code:

```
import 'dart:html;
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:staffattendence05/Usermodel.dart';
import 'package:staffattendence05/add_user.dart';
import 'package:staffattendence05/authenticate.dart';
import 'package:staffattendence05/fauth.dart';
import 'package:staffattendence05/home.dart';
import 'package:staffattendence05/styling.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:staffattendence05/loading.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'Login_ins.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  @override
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String email = '';

  String error = '';

  String password = '';

  bool loading = false;

  final Authservice _auth = Authservice();

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
            appBar: AppBar(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
              title: Text(
                "Register your institute",
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: FlatButton.icon(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Loginins()),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                    label: Text("institute Login"),
                    color: Colors.teal,
                  ),
                )
              ],
              backgroundColor: Colors.green[400],
            ),
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _formkey,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 120.0,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: styling.copyWith(hintText: "Admin email"),
                      validator: (val) {
                        return val.isEmpty
                            ? "please enter an valid email id"
                            : null;
                      },
                      onChanged: (val) {
                        email = val;
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      decoration: styling.copyWith(hintText: "Admin password"),
                      validator: (val) => val.length < 6
                          ? "a password should contain atleast 6 characters"
                          : null,
                      onChanged: (val) => password = val,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 25.0,
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7)),
                      color: Colors.green[400],
                      child: Text(
                        "Register",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                          setState(() {
                            loading = true;
                          });
                          Position Insposition = await getCurrentPosition(
                              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
                          dynamic result =
                              await _auth.Signupwithemailandpassword(
                                  email, password, Insposition);
                          final String adminname = email;
                          double distanceInMeters = distanceBetween(
                              52.2165157, 6.9437819, 52.3546274, 4.8285838);
                          print("1111111111111$adminname");
                          print(Insposition);
                          if (result == null) {
                            setState(() {
                              loading = false;
                              error = 'Please enter a valid email address!';
                            });
                          } else {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Home(
                                        adminname: adminname,
                                      )),
                            );
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Text(
                      error,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red[400],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 14),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

`it would be appreciable if someone point the mistake i did.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Solved]

Distance Between

```
GeolocatorPlatform.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude);
```

For Bearing distance

```
GeolocatorPlatform.bearingBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude);
```

At the time of writing this answer official documentation is not correct. I tried both other answers above and not worked if that's the case with you try these code it worked for me and hopefully this will fix your problem too. [ version : geolocator 6.0.0+1 ]

git https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/496#issuecomment-683861804

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the GitHub page and source for the package, the documentation on pub.dev appears to be out of date. The correct usage seems to be:

```dart
double distanceInMeters = GeolocatorPlatform.instance.distanceBetween(
  52.2165157, 
  6.9437819, 
  52.3546274, 
  4.8285838,
);
```

Comment: both `GeolocatorPlatform.instance` and `Geolocator.distanceBetween` worked for me in `7.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
                              52.2165157, 6.9437819, 52.3546274, 4.8285838);
```

Comment: Neither is there a `Geolocator` class in the package, nor is the `distanceBetween` method asynchronous.

Comment: It might not be a asynchronous function, but there is surely a Geolocator package, this is where i think he's getting wrong. import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';..check once again

Comment: There is a geolocator package. There is not a `Geolocator` _class._

Comment: Yup you're right, i just checked the docs, bt i think he should give it a go.. except tht await

Comment: your answer would be correct for the older version of the geolocator package.Since they updated version from 5.x to 6.x yesterday your answer is not suitable to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

None of the above are in my geolocator package - I have already done flutter pub upgrade and on my pubspec.yaml, the reference is as: geolocator:
The code which resolved my issue was:

```
 double distance = await geolocator.distanceBetween(double.tryParse(lat1),
    double.tryParse(long1), double.tryParse(lat2), double.tryParse(long2));
```